# World dataset of hospitals

Tags: geospatial, medical

I am looking for a (global) dataset of hospitals: mainly locations, but if possible also names, sizes, number of beds. As far as I can tell, this does not exist yet, but perhaps there are good starting points!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[healthsites.io](https://healthsites.io/) is an open data effort to map healthcare entities (hospitals, clinics, pharmacies, private practices, etc.) worldwide.  The data is drawn from OpenStreetMap and at a minimum provides the name and geographic coordinates of each healthcare entity.  There is a OSM data model for health sites, details provided [here](https://github.com/healthsites/healthsites/wiki/Healthsite-attributes).  The data is released under the Open Data License.

Comment: fantastic! have you used the dataset?

Comment: I have not personally used this data but I have used OpenStreetMap data in the past

Comment: good day - i think that healthsites.io only has got a small subset of the data that is collected at openstreetmap- .. i personally think that you find much much more data at the endpoint of osm  . check it out  ...